# Remove the "Quorum" badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, meta

It seems like the [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/900/quorum) badge will just flood meta with a bunch of unrelated meta requests. Granted, that's why I'm posting but it would seem more conducive to real conversations in meta to remove the badge.

Comment: I love the irony, and agree. Supposedly badges are for rewarding positive behavior, you should get a badge for reading the FAQ, instead of posting the 90th version of "[Why was my question closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Why+was+my+question+closed)". EDIT: Wait, *is* there even a badge for "First post on meta"? or are you talking about the [Quorum](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/900/quorum) badge?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Notice something that's almost universally true about the linked "Why was my question closed" questions: their score is almost unanimously less than 0, and on the first page, only one is above 2. (and yes, he's talking about the Quorum badge, as it's the only one-post-on-meta badge)

Comment: @Wesley You do get a badge for [reading the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1306/analytical)

Comment: My mistake, I recalled a badge for simply posting on meta regardless of score that doesn't actually exist. Removed upvote as I now do not totally agree. jason, I've edited with details on which badge you meant, if this is not correct please clarify. @Michael: That's awesome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One benefit of badges in general are that they encourage exploration of the site and its features. Many newer users really start exploring the chat, meta, off-topic flagging, or bounties features when they see badges for them and become curious. The rationale for quorum badge is the same: it encourages people to become active in different aspects of the site, which ultimately encourages more people to become more active with the site overall.

I vote to leave the quorum badge because, like others have said, it isn't simply awarded to anyone who leaves a post; there must be enough posts with a score of 2+. And in case you haven't noticed from the voting response to this question, it's more difficult to get upvotes in meta than SO.

Answer (score 9):

That's what are badges for, to attract more and more people giving their feedback.

Bronze badge is given only after one post with score >= 2 and silver one is given after 10 posts with score >= 2. If there are people who are posting bad answers/questions, they get downvoted and they never have chance to obtain that badge.

I wouldn't care about that